SharePoint Library Choice Column - Modify without Grid View - JSON Formatting
I have a SharePoint Library with a choice column ("yes" and no" values) in which I want the user to be able to modify without entering Grid View.  The idea is for the user to create a new doc set, upload documents, then update this field = Yes to trigger an approval flow.  The Json I entered looks correct on the surface, but when I click the field, the value disappears, rather than allowing me to select either "Yes" or "No".
How it looks before clicking on it: 
How it looks after clicking on the field: 
Here is my JSON code:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "Yes"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "No"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-borderColor-DustRoseFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-DustRoseFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField",
                        ""
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I had this field as a Yes/No field initially, but I want the user's experience to be a Dropdown, rather than a Checkbox.  And I couldn't figure out a way to present that in w Y/N column.

You could remove the existing formatting and use the following (make sure you use the correct field name). Maybe @currentField is not allowed for this kind of JSON.
 //In the example below, [ReadyForApproval] is a Choice column
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "[$ReadyForApproval]",
  "txtContent": "[$ReadyForApproval]"
}


See more examples on JSON formatting at Advanced formatting concepts

